# CORS issue while calling WEB API using angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on my first demo application which is used to display person details on UI using web api and angular JS. My code is working fine if I am launching Chrome using "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security", however it's not working for normal Chrome/IE. I did some debugging and found that seems CORS issue. I tried to enable CORS at api end as well but not working for me. Can someone please help me to make it working. Thanks in advance. Below is my code snippet:

WebAPI:

```js
 public class HomeController : ApiController
 { 
 public HttpResponseMessage GetPersonDetails()
 {
 var person = new List<person>
 {
 new Person {Id=1, Address="Pune", Name="Test1"},
 new Person {Id=2, Address="Pune", Name="Test2"},
 new Person {Id=3, Address="Pune", Name="Test3"},
 new Person {Id=4, Address="Pune", Name="Test4"}
 };
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, person); 
 }
 }
```

angular code:

```js
var appModule = angular.module("MyApp", []);

appModule.controller('getUserDetailsController', function ($scope, $http) {
           $http({
               method: 'GET',
               url: 'http://localhost:61896/api/Home/GetPersonDetails',
               headers: {

                   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

               },
               contentType:'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
           }).then(function (response) {

               $scope.objUserDetails = response.data;


           });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to enable CORS at api end, also tried to send header from js, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Do you have EnableCors attribute in your api controller. If yest can you post it. I am able to call the api from different port by using the same code you posted above.

Comment: Hi Anil, Thanks for looking into this. Yes, I did that by adding [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:61896", headers: "*", methods: "*")] on top of my controller class.

 [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:61896", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {        
        public HttpResponseMessage GetPersonDetails()
        {
            }

       }

Comment: Please share your WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Hi Marcus.. I have not added anything to my web config file. I was trying to attach code here but it was too long so adding in phases.
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>  
  </system.web>

Comment: <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>

Comment: <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

As per your reply, there are few corrections that you need to make in your attribute.

- Remove semicolon from orgins
- Add * in headers and methods

  [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:61896", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Just use above EnableCors attribute as it is and your issue should be resolved.

**Note: Somehow * is always removed when i post the answer. Don't forget to add * if its not there in your headers and methods.**

Second thing is to look for having config.EnableCors() in your Register method of WebApiConfig.cs file

Comment: Hi Anil.. "*(star)" is already present in EnableCors attribute. However it's same for me as well, it's not showing here. and there is not semicolon.

Comment: Can you cross check the config.EnableCors() option mentioned in my edited answer above

Comment: That is already configured:
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Enable CoRS
            config.EnableCors();

            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults:  new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }